# using em or percentage for CSS grid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a 3-4 page web site. It will use jQuery, jQuery UI and Ajax calls for most of the pages. I hope not to have to code anything in pixels.

So far I I have spent a few days looking at solutions and my head is spinning as I cannot see what I want. I am trying to decide how best to lay out the web site so that it is responsive and so it adapts well to changes in browser size. It seems to me that pages designed using percentage or em resize a lot better than those using fixed px for layout.

Not sure but I think using a "grid" such as golden grid or some of the others out there would be overkill. I am thinking of doing something like this?

```
#container {
  max-width: 75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#primary {
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
}

#content {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}

#secondary {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
```

Should I use percentage for widths or should I somehow do this with ems. I hope that I can get some good suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: If it is really simple the interior should be a % the exterior is up to you...it's more a matter of preference

Comment: It's always a trade-off. Things that are always 25% wide will likely turn out to be too narrow on a smart phone, but too wide on a full-HD desktop monitor. Some things need a width in percentages, other things need a width in `em` or `ch`. If you keep the blocks floating (and you can live with the disadvantages of floats) the result may look OK on both narrow and wide screens. But don't count on it. Test!

Answer (score 2):

First: In your case use percentages. 
Percentages orient on their parent elements, whereas em is based on font-size. If you want to resize your site based on browsersize, use %, if you want your site to resize whenever the user changes the font-size, use em.

Some additional ideas:

From my experience the choice of %,px,em depends on the project (and thus the goal of the website).

If the site is some sort of portfolio, I may suggest using pixelbased layouts. (Since most people view them as digital version of their work and want it to look exactly like the (prelayouted) draft).
This way you get a nice result, but may run into problems when resizing the site (e.g. text gets to big).

In this case, (obviously) relative systems are better, since they scale well. This is often times more user-friendly, since you have the guarantee that the container scale appropriate.
Use this if you want to make the site more accessable.

Keep in mind, that you can use pixel-based/relative layouts and still solve the other problems. Often times the overall layout is %-based but some containers are pixel-based.

And since you are using JS to enhance your site, you could use it, to resize the site on the fly or do other stuff (although I would not recommend this, if it is not neccesary, due to the fact, that not everybody uses JS(but this is another story))

Answer (score 1):

You could use this: http://grids.heroku.com/ and choose the fluid width option when you preview / download it.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the link that you gave me.